# Hive Configuration change using Apache Drill

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hive, apache-drill

I want to using Hive metastore using Drill.

But I have no idea changing Configuration Drill web UI.

Hive is running in Local and Only one Node using, Not distributed

- Hive path : /usr/local/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin
- Drill path : /usr/local/hadoop/apache-drill-1.8.0
- Haddop path : /usr/local/hadoop

Configuration is like this

```
{
  "type": "hive",    
  "enabled": true,    
  "configProps": {    
  "hive.metastore.uris": "",    
  "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": "jdbc:derby:;databaseName=../sample-data/drill_hive_db;create=true",   
  "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir": "file:///usr/local/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/metastore_db",   
  "fs.default.name": "file:///",  
  "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false"
  }
```

}

Because first using Hive, I don't know what option what exactly work.

Drill, HDFS and Hive have only one node and exist in Local.

How can I fix it?? what's options are essential?

Comment: Hive metastore is embedded or you used any other like mysql, postgres?

Comment: just embedded, not using mysql

Comment: then just add this plugin you mentioned in the question. Are you facing any error while adding this plugin?

Comment: I do drill's hive configuration enable, but hive table can't be read.
In my hive have sample table to testing, drill doesn't read this table